# Okular annotations auto-save

Tags: okular

I was reviewing a pdf paper using okular. I would choose save-as to save the document in which I highlighted text, but I did not do that recently.

I was also multi-tasking between other things I'm doing or that require my attention. Later I realized that somehow, the okular session in which I was annotating (reviewing) the pdf paper had been inadvertently closed and I've lost my annotations for the last half day.

Is there any auto-save feature in okular that can enable me to recover the lost annotations instead of having to redo them?

Comment: Huh, that is interesting. My Okular appears to save the annotations automatically. What version are you using?

Comment: Okular Version 0.23.2 using KDE Platform 4.14.13

Comment: @edwinksl I believe they are referring to saving PDF annotations to file as opposed to Okular annotations (which are not saved to the PDF)

Answer (score 1):

To me Okular saves the annotations automatically, just like @edwinksl says in the comments. Using Okular Version `0.24.2` & PDF Backend Version `0.6.5` (whatever that is) & KDE platform Version `4.14.16`

Comment: I believe @Chah is referring to saving PDF annotations to file as opposed to Okular annotations (which are not saved to the PDF). I have the same issue as them

Comment: I don't exactly understand everything, but there's an option `file > print` and "print to file (pdf)". This will allow you to create a new file with no annotations. They will be part of the pdf itself. I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for. Also there's a problem with the size of the pages. You might get unwanted white space. You can try and fix that through "Properties", "Page size". There's "custom" and you can set the width and the height. @craymichael